# Match key from Object to element in an array replace match with keys value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to exactly match the key from an Object to an element in an array and replace the match in the array with the key value.

I have

```
Arr = [ 'Saturday', 'niCCCght', 'plans,', 'CCC' ]

Obj = { "AAA": "BBB", "CCC": "DDD", "EEE": "FFF" }
```

with below I get

```
[ 
  [ 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday' ],
  [ 'niCCCght', 'niCCCght', 'niCCCght' ],
  [ 'plans,', 'plans,', 'plans,' ],
  [ 'CCC', 'DDD', 'CCC' ] 
]
```

I want

```
[ 'Saturday', 'niCCCght', 'plans,', 'DDD' ]
```

Thank you

```
function test() {
  let Arr = [ 'Saturday', 'niCCCght', 'plans,', 'CCC' ];

  const Obj = {"AAA":"BBB", "CCC":"DDD","EEE":"FFF"};
  
  const Z = Arr.map(v => matchedKey(Obj,v))

  console.log(Z);
}
let matchedKey = (Obj,str) => Object.keys(Obj).map(key => key===str ? Obj[key]: str);
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Where exactly are you struggling?

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Simply `map()` over the input array and search for a matching property name in the object. If one is found, return that property value otherwise the original value:

```js
const arr = ['Saturday', 'niCCCght', 'plans,', 'CCC']
const obj = { "AAA": "BBB", "CCC": "DDD", "EEE": "FFF" }

var output = arr.map(v => obj[v] ?? v);
console.log(output);
```

Alternatively you can use `hasOwnProperty()` which is a little more descriptive in outlining what the logic is doing. The output of both will be the same, though.

```
var output = arr.map(v => obj.hasOwnProperty(v) ? obj[v] : v);
```

Comment: hmm, I have not seen `??` before

Comment: `Nullish coalescing operator '??'` I like https://javascript.info/nullish-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 1):

Just going through all of the obj keys and when I find a  match I replace that idx with obj value for that key

```
function test() {
  var arr = ['Saturday', 'niCCCght', 'plans,', 'CCC'];
  const obj = { "AAA": "BBB", "CCC": "DDD", "EEE": "FFF" };
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    let idx = arr.indexOf(k)
    if (~idx) arr[idx] = obj[k];
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

Execution log
1:24:36 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:24:30 PM  Info    ["Saturday","niCCCght","plans,","DDD"]
1:24:38 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```